# Отключить ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброй ночи. Вопрос такой: нужно отключить `ContextMenu`, если кликнули не на `ListItem`.
Обычным `HitTest` в ListView не получается сделать. 
Создавать отдельно менюшку в XAML, а затем кидать ее в `ItemContainerStyle`тоже не подойдет, так как используются библиотеки, в которых есть встроенные style-ы, и менять их запрещено. Соответственно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18921462/7099288) сделать нельзя.
Есть какие-нибудь варианты?

**UPDATE:**
В *App.xaml* есть подключенный словарь ресурсов, такой себе super-словарь:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Some;component/Styles/ControlStyles.xaml" />
```

В *MainWindow.xaml* я создаю `ContextMenu` как ресурс:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Пункт меню" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</ListView.Resources>
```

и затем добавляю его в `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType ="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource contextMenu}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

И получается, что я полностью теряю стиль моего `ListViewItem`, определенный в словаре ресурсов в `App.xaml`.

Comment: А содержимое контекстного меню вам не важно?

Comment: А откуда у вас там взялось контекстное меню? В стоковом ListView его нету. Покажите ваш код, без него нам придётся угадывать, в чём дело.

Comment: Если у вас нет меню, и вы хотите добавить его для айтемов, ну так сделайте производный стиль (`BasedOn`).

Comment: @VladD, мне нужно сделать вызов контекстного меню только при нажатии на `ListViewItem`, если это сделано за пределами, то не вызывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за `BasedOn`:

```
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType ="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource contextMenu}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```